# Looking for a more efficient (and portable) way to obtain (numeric) file permissions in unix

Tags: unix, shell, sed, awk, zabbix

Short background: I need to monitor the permissions on a unix file (a directory) with ZABBIX to see if/when they change. ZABBIX doesn't have any built in like vfs.file.mode[xxxx] for this, so I had to roll my own UserParameter, with a numeric type.

What I do so far, is use `ls -l | cut -c 2-10` to get the `rwxr-xr-x`part, and then use `sed` to convert letters to their "weight", and `awk` with `substr` to sum it up, to get the numeric `755` or whatever value.

This is currently on Solaris, I don't have GNU coreutils `stat` command, and I want it to be portable and efficient, and only using standard unix tools, that are always available. (IMHO, perl is not always available).

My first attempt (example for the root directory):

```
ls -ld / | \
cut -c 2-10 | \
sed -e 's%-%0%g' -e 's%r%4%g' -e 's%w%2%g' -e 's%x%1%g' | \
awk '{print (100 * ((substr($0,1,1)) + (substr($0,2,1)) + (substr($0,3,1))) + \
     (10 * ((substr($0,4,1) + (substr($0,5,1)) + (substr($0,6,1)) ))) + \
     ( (substr($0,7,1)) + (substr($0,8,1)) + (substr($0,9,1)) ) );}'
```

As you can see, I don't care about setuid bits or anything other than files, but purist responses are always welcome!

Surely there must be a more elegant solution. Perhaps a standard unix tool that I didn't think of.

I found this place "accidentally" about a week ago, and I really really love it! Amazing to see that much knowledge, skills, and friendliness in one place!
This is my first question, so I'm really excited to see if I get any response! :-)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What you are looking for is readily available via system calls. There is no need to reinvent the wheel, except for "fun".

Comment: The thing is that writing my own `stat(2)` wrapper actually _is_ reinventing the wheel. I need something I can put in a config file without needing to install extra programs on the hosts being monitored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is any more elegant/efficient than your own version but I will put it up in case any of the techniques are useful for improving your own. This could obviously be done much more simply/elegantly with a script though

The basic premise is to use tr to translate the rwx to the relevant octal numbers, then use sed to split into groups of 3 add pluses and then generate an awk command string whicg gets passed to awk to add them up.

```
ls -ld / | \
cut -c2-10 | \
tr 'rwx-t' '42100' | \
sed -E -e 's/(...)(...)(...)/\1 \2 \3/g' \
-e 's/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])/\1+\2+\3/g' \
-e 's/^(.*)$/BEGIN {print \1}/g'|\
awk -f -`
```

Comment: My `tr` complained about the hyphen unless I escaped it. Your first and third `g` aren't necessary. Here's a GNU sed version of yours which is greatly simplified. It could be easily converted back to the `-e` form. `ls -ld / cur -c2-10 | tr 'rwx\-t' '42100' | sed -r 's/(...)/\1 /g;s/([0-9])/\1+0/g;s/.*/BEGIN {print &}/' | awk -f -`

Comment: I always place the hyphen last when I use `tr` or write regular expressions.
Of course `tr` is more elegant than my initial `sed` for doing the same thing. Thanks, Steve! I'll see if I can use `bc` or `expr` instead of awk.

Answer (score 4):

if you can use `find` then this looks better:

`find FILENAME -prune -printf '%m\n'`

found it [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.unix.shell/browse_thread/thread/f2c50db11c3cb1f4)

Answer (score 1):

If your system has `bash`, and `ls -l` shows file permissions (rwxrwxrwx), you may accomplish what you were looking for with the following example:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ ! -d $1 ] && echo "Error: "$1" is not a directory" && exit 1 
set -- `ls -ld $1`;P=${1:1:9};P=${P//r/4 };P=${P//w/2 };P=${P//x/1 };P=${P//-/0 }
set -- $P; echo $((($1+$2)+$3))$((($4+$5)+$6))$((($7+$8)+$9))
```

The advantage is that other utilities such as awk or sed are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

`stat` should have what you're looking for.  Try one of these:

```
stat -c "%a" <filename>
```

or

```
stat --printf="%a" <filename>
```

Comment: The stat command doesn't come with all unices. That's why I wrote that I didn't want to use it.

Comment: Ah, crap. I missed that note in your post. Sorry :^)

Comment: `stat` the command line tool may not, but there is such a system call available with all unix distributions.

Answer (score 0):

This is long-winded, but I think it's more maintainable than yours. You can call it like this: `ls -ld / | cut -c 2-10 | ./perm.awk`.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
# OR: #!/usr/bin/nawk -f

function conv(num, len, i, val) {
    # converts binary string to decimal (or octal if fed 3 "bits" at a time)
    # call with num as argument, others are local variables
    len = length(num)
    for(i = len; i > 0; i--) {
        if (substr(num, i, 1) == 1) {
            val = val + 2 ^ (len - i)
        }
    }
    return val
}

# main loop
{
    # TODO: handle [sStT]
    gsub("[rwx]", 1)    # make it look binary
    gsub("-", 0)
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        perm = perm conv(substr($0, i * 3 + 1, 3))    # convert the "bits" 3 at a time
    }
}

END {
    print perm
}
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks! I'm kinda looking for something that don't require any extra installs/files right now, though.

Answer (score 0):

Implementations of `ls` vary, so your `ls` is not really portable either.

I'd solve this problem using [Lua](http://www.lua.org/), which compiles on any ANSI Standard C platform, together with the [Lua POSIX library](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lposix), which should build out of the box on any POSIX platform.  There you can make your `stat` call directly and write clear simple code to do the arithmetic.  An excellent introduction to Lua [*Programming in Lua*](http://www.lua.org/pil/) is available free online (for the previous version of Lua).  Finally, if you care about efficiency, the results will be *extremely* efficient, partly because Lua is fast, but mostly because you will be able to do everything while forking only one process—the Lua interpreter.

Comment: Lua looks interesting. I will definitely look into it (for other things).